# Symbolic link to host-shared folder from vmPlayer guest results in permissions errors

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, sublime-text-2, vmware-player

I have my Sublime packages located at `C:/Storage/Dropbox/settings/sublime-text-2/` on my Windows 7 host.

In my Ubuntu 13.04 guest, I have mounted the `Storage` folder at `/mnt/hgfs/`. Ergo, the location of the settings on the guest is `/mnt/hgfs/Dropbox/settings/sublime-text-2/`.

The location where Sublime Text 2 saves configuration in Ubuntu is `~/.config/sublime-text-2/`. I have made a symlink here to point to the mounted settings file.

This *should* work. However, when I access Sublime Text 2, I receive a package permission denied error:

**`OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: /mnt/hgfs/Dropbox/settings/sublime-text-2/Pristine Packages/XML.sublime-package`**

---

Any tips?

This is my `/etc/fstab` entry for mounting the host-shared `Storage` folder which contains my Dropbox:

`.host:/Storage /mnt/hgfs vmhgfs defaults,ttl=5,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0`

(I've already changed the ownership and permissions in the `Dropbox/settings/sublime-text-2/` to my user and `777`. I've had a similar setup working before.)

Comment: do you just get the error for the XML package file, or for everything?

Comment: Everything. It fails on the first package to attempts to overwrite, but this is random and so I have seen it error with various other ST2 packages (e.g. `Lua.sublime-package` or `PHP.sublime-package`).

Comment: Are you sure it is symlink and not alias?

Comment: Yeah. `ln -s /mnt/hgfs/Dropbox/settings/sublime-text-2/ sublime-text-2`